# Why isn't complex conjugation a *-homomorphism?

Tags: c-star-algebras

By Gelfand-duality with $1$, the set $\{pt\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathrm{Spec}(C(\{pt\})) \cong \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C})$, the set of nonzero *-homomorphisms $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with the pointwise convergence topology.

In particular, there can be only one * -homomorphism $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. But why can't I take both $id$ and complex conjugation (*) itself?

Comment: Look at the definition of $*$-homomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $^*$-homomorphism is a [linear map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map), but complex conjugation is [antilinear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antilinear_map)